# Using quick sort to sort elements by frequency: how can I order elements of same frequency by size?

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to solve this question in Python using quick sort:

> Given an array A[] of integers, sort the array according to frequency of elements. That is elements that have higher frequency come first. If frequencies of two elements are same, then smaller number comes first.

I've created an array to store the number of occurrences of each integer in A[], as follows:

```
def find_count(arr, n):
    count = [0]*(max(arr)+1)
    for i in arr:
        count[i] += 1
    return count
```

Next, I've used quick sort to sort the elements in decreasing order of number of occurrences:

```
def quicksort(arr, low, high, count):
    if(low < high):
        i = low
        j = high
        pivot = low
        while(i < j):
            while(i < high and count[arr[i]] >= count[arr[pivot]]):
                i += 1
            while(count[arr[j]] < count[arr[pivot]]):
                j -= 1
            if(i < j):
                arr[i], arr[j] = arr[j], arr[i]
        arr[pivot], arr[j] = arr[j], arr[pivot]
        quicksort(arr, low, j-1, count)
        quicksort(arr, j+1, high, count)
```

This method works to sort elements in decreasing order of frequency. However, elements with the same frequency appear in an unpredictable order (not in increasing order of size as required):

```
For Input:
[5, 5, 4, 6, 4]
your output is: 
[5, 4, 4, 5, 6]
required output:
[4, 4, 5, 5, 6]
```

How can I implement a condition to order elements with the same frequency in increasing order of their size?

Comment: Can you explain your input and output?  Why isn't each an array of integers?

Comment: I processed the input and converted it to an array of integers, and converted the output array to a space separated string. I'll post that part if you're interested

Comment: @Shield77--I assumed it toe a space-separated string, but was confused why things are on two lines.  Taking it as a space-separated integer on two lines I didn't follow the sort order.  What would have been preferred would have been an input array (Python list) and a desired outptu array (Python list).

Comment: They were two different input-output sets, sorry for the lack of clarity. I'll edit to remove the second line of both

Comment: @Shield77--it's okay to have both, but you should comment that it's two test cases.

Comment: @DarrylG--thanks, will keep it in mind for next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You modify quicksort so it uses a key function

- similarly to how Python sort function uses a key function
- More general solution since can sort by other criteria by using a different key function

**Modified Code**

```
def find_count(arr, n):
    count = [0]*(max(arr)+1)
    for i in arr:
        count[i] += 1
    return count

def quicksort(arr, low, high, keyfunc):
    if(low < high):
        i = low
        j = high
        pivot = low
        while i < j:
            while i < high and keyfunc(arr[i]) >= keyfunc(arr[pivot]):
                i += 1
            while keyfunc(arr[j]) < keyfunc(arr[pivot]):
                j -= 1
            if i < j:
                arr[i], arr[j] = arr[j], arr[i]
        arr[pivot], arr[j] = arr[j], arr[pivot]
        quicksort(arr, low, j-1, keyfunc)
        quicksort(arr, j+1, high, keyfunc)
```

**Test**

```
a = [5, 5, 4, 6, 4]
count = find_count(a, len(a))

# Use key function based upon tuple of count and value (use -v since want lower values first)
quicksort(a, 0, len(a)-1, lambda v: (count[v], -v)) 
# new a: [5, 5, 4, 6, 4]

# Change key function to sort strings
a = ['to', 'be', 'or', 'not', 'to', 'be', 'a', 'fool']
quicksort(a, 0, len(a)-1, lambda v: (-len(v), v))
# new a: ['a', 'to', 'to', 'or', 'be', 'be', 'not', 'fool']
```

Comment: Thanks, that was a real help!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by modifying the quicksort() function to only swap elements of equal frequency if they are in the wrong order of size:

```
def quicksort(arr, low, high, count):
if(low < high):
    i = low
    j = high
    pivot = low
    while(i < j):
        while(i < high and (count[arr[i]] > count[arr[pivot]] or
           (count[arr[i]] == count[arr[pivot]] and arr[i] <= arr[pivot]))):
            i += 1
        while( j >= low and count[arr[j]] < count[arr[pivot]] or
           (count[arr[j]] == count[arr[pivot]] and arr[j] > arr[pivot])):
            j -= 1
        if(i < j):
            arr[i], arr[j] = arr[j], arr[i]
    arr[pivot], arr[j] = arr[j], arr[pivot]
    quicksort(arr, low, j-1, count)
    quicksort(arr, j+1, high, count)
```

In this way, I was able to sort the array according to the required conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You create a map and store the frequency. Now use quick sort to sort frequency array. When you swap the frequency array, swap the main array elements too.

```
package javaapplication4;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class QuickSort {

    int arr[];
    int freq[];
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    QuickSort(int arr[]) {
        this.arr = arr;
        freq = new int[arr.length];
    }
 
    void qsortByFrequency(int low, int high) {
        if (low < high) {

            int pi = partitionByFrequency(low, high);
            qsortByFrequency(low, pi - 1);
            qsortByFrequency(pi + 1, high);
        }
    }

    int partitionByFrequency(int low, int high) {
        int pivot = freq[high];
        int i = low - 1;
        int j;
        for (j = low; j <= high; j++) {
            if (freq[j] < pivot) {
                i++;
                int temp = freq[i];
                freq[i] = freq[j];
                freq[j] = temp;

                temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
            }
        }
        int temp = freq[i + 1];
        freq[i + 1] = freq[high];
        freq[high] = temp;

        temp = arr[i + 1];
        arr[i + 1] = arr[high];
        arr[high] = temp;
        return i + 1;
    }

    void getFrequency() {

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (map.containsKey(arr[i])) {
                int c = map.get(arr[i]);
                map.put(arr[i], ++c);

            } else {
                map.put(arr[i], 1);

            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < this.arr.length; i++) {
            int el = arr[i];
            int c = map.get(arr[i]);
            freq[i] = c;
        }

        System.out.println("FreqMap " + map);
        this.qsortByFrequency(0, this.freq.length - 1);

    }

    void getSortedArray() {

        System.out.println(" Quick Sorted Array ");
        for (int i = 0; i < this.arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println(" -- ");
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.