# How sorted() function is able to sort with custom key in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Below is my code for for sorting the list.

```
def sorthelper(x):
     return x[1]

ls=[('data2',1),('data1',3),('data3',2)]

print(sorted(ls,key=sorthelper))
```

Here I am able to define custom key and accordingly list is sorted  and got the expected result.

What keeps intriguing  me  that how `sorted()` function is working internally with key to sort the list ? How value of variable `key` is used for sorting ?

My understanding is `sorthelper()` (defined by me for returing key) is getting called multiple time and returning the key

Is variable `key` is maintaining some sort of list of all returned keys to sort original list ? If yes then requesting to explain the working as well.

I have tried to search as much as possible but didn't found any such explanation of my question.

Also Please bear with me for my bad English writing. Thanks for the understanding.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted)?

Comment: @shree.pat18 I have checked now. I have not found any explanation how key is actually helpful in sorting. Thanks for the response though.

Comment: Check out: [Sorting HOW TO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html)

Comment: @DarrylG , Looks like I have failed to make question understandable . Still I am struggling to find how actually key is helping to inbuilt sorted function.Let me put it  in an another way . Why list is not getting sorted when key returing function `sorthelper()` returning any fix value , let say the value is 9 ? how this returned  key is getting compared to each item in the list while sorting process is being performed.

Comment: "Why list is not getting sorted when key returing function sorthelper() returning any fix value" -- the answer is Python uses a stable sort algorithm meaning if two items have the same key, their order will be preserved in the sorted list.

Comment: @DarrylG How python compares the key with each item ?

Comment: Without a key funciton to compare elements in list `arr` at indexes i & j we have `arr[i] >= arr[j]`.  With the key function, say function `keyfunc`, we pass values through the key function before the comparison to get: `keyfunc(arr[i]) >= keyfunc(arr[j])`.  An example is my modification of quicksort to add a key function as shown by [Using quick sort to sort elements by frequency: how can I order elements of same frequency by size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67280332/using-quick-sort-to-sort-elements-by-frequency-how-can-i-order-elements-of-same/67281248#67281248)

Comment: @DarrylG That's rather misleading, especially since they've already wondered about "getting called multiple time" and "list of all returned keys".

Comment: @KellyBundy -- please expand on how it's misleading.  I was only mentioning the key function is applied in the comparison operation.  The number of times is controlled by many comparisons are done.  Efficient algorithms like quicksort perform O(n*log(n)) on average comparisons.  This makes the number of times the key function is called in these algorithms also on the order of O(n*log(n)).

Comment: @DarrylG Oh so you actually don't know... The key function is called exactly n times, once for each element. Before the actual sorting begins. The keys are stored and those stored keys are used during the actual sorting (instead of the key function).

Comment: @KellyBundy -- thanks for pointing that out.  So, in my quicksort example code I should have first redefined the input array as `arr = [keyfunc(v) for v in arr]`, then performed a quicksort on the revised arr.  Good to know.  Thanks.

Comment: @DarrylG Something like that, yes. And then both the values array and the keys array get sorted in parallel (by key). I.e., the keys array gets sorted and all moves are applied to the values array as well.

Comment: Hi @KellyBundy, Can you please  help to know how sorted  key iist help to sort  origingal list?